# Create a background task in IntelliJ plugin

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm developing an IntelliJ-idea plugin and want to run code in background task (visible in the background tasks dialog and in another thread than the UI).

I found the following [Helper class](https://github.com/inmite/android-selector-chapek/blob/master/src/utils/RunnableHelper.java) and tried it by passing a Runnable object and implement its run method but it still blocking the UI and when I tried to do the threading myself i got the following error

```
 Read access is allowed from event dispatch thread or inside read-action only (see com.intellij.openapi.application.Application.runReadAction())
     Details: Current thread: Thread[Thread-69 [WriteAccessToken],6,Idea Thread Group] 532224832
     Our dispatch thread:Thread[AWT-EventQueue-1 12.1.4#IU-129.713, eap:false,6,Idea Thread Group] 324031064
     SystemEventQueueThread: Thread[AWT-EventQueue-1 12.1.4#IU-129.713, eap:false,6,Idea Thread Group] 324031064
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have found a better way to run the process as background task where you can update the progress bar percentage and text

```
ProgressManager.getInstance().run(new Task.Backgroundable(project, "Title"){
        public void run(@NotNull ProgressIndicator progressIndicator) {

            // start your process

            // Set the progress bar percentage and text
            progressIndicator.setFraction(0.10);
            progressIndicator.setText("90% to finish");


            // 50% done
            progressIndicator.setFraction(0.50);
            progressIndicator.setText("50% to finish");


            // Finished
            progressIndicator.setFraction(1.0);
            progressIndicator.setText("finished");

        }});
```

If you need to read some data from another thread you should use

```
AccessToken token = null;
try {
   token = ApplicationManager.getApplication().acquireReadActionLock();
                    //do what you need
} finally {
   token.finish();
}
```

Comment: Can you Please add more code on how to dismiss the progress indicator, and how to use the token to change the UI

Answer (score 11):

Here is the general solution

```
ApplicationManager.getApplication().executeOnPooledThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        ApplicationManager.getApplication().runReadAction(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
            // do whatever you need to do
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Where should this code be kept so that this gets executed as soon as the build is complete?

Answer (score 2):

New way to run backgroundable task with kotlin

```kotlin
import com.intellij.openapi.progress.runBackgroundableTask

runBackgroundableTask("My Backgrund Task", project) {
    for (i in 0..10 step 1) {
        it.checkCanceled()
        it.fraction = i / 10.0
        sleep(i * 100L)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As described in API :

> Causes doRun.run() to be executed asynchronously on the AWT event
> dispatching thread. This will happen after all pending AWT events have
> been processed. This method should be used when an application thread
> needs to update the GUI.

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater {
    // do something 
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.