# use property "idea.config.path" in IDEA plugin ,but value is null

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

- I just use `String path = System.getProperty("idea.config.path");` in `actionPerformed` method,then I got null..
- But when debugging my plugin, this property can be found and value is `C:\Users\myusername\.IntelliJIdea2017.1\system\plugins-sandbox`
- At last,I use `System.getProperties().store(new FileWriter(new File("C:/temp/a.txt")), "");` to get all properties into a file,and there really doesn't exist a `"idea.config.path"` property in `a.txt` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should [use the API instead](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/e93716a05b98f729c6a7e21ffe84396e6bf41712/platform/util/src/com/intellij/openapi/application/PathManager.java#L210).

```
com.intellij.openapi.application.PathManager#getConfigPath
```

Comment: May I ask an other question..
 I just use this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18725340/create-a-background-task-in-intellij-plugin) to read file in background task,and then I got "Access is allowed from event dispatch thread only." 
what should I do...

Comment: I've already replied to your question via the support ticket, please see http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/architectural_overview/general_threading_rules.html for details. Don't ask multiple question in one or in the comments for the answer. Always submit a new question instead. Also consider accepting the answer if it was helpful. Please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work.